# if two drives in a system - getting hard disk number - VC++

Tags: numbers, disk, hard-drive

If two drives in a system - How to get Hard Disk Number? How to get in order (primary & secondary).

Answer (score 1):

You can emumerate the volumes (drives) attached in the system with
[FindFirstVolume Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextVolume Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364431%28VS.85%29.aspx). ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456%28VS.85%29.aspx))

To filter out drives that are not hard disks use the [GetDriveType Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28VS.85%29.aspx).